# Complete Bipartite Graph, Euler and Hamiltonian Circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

I just need some confirmation on if these Complete Bipartite Graph are Euler Circuit and Hamiltonian Circuit.

$K_{1,1}$  --> Not Euler Circuit (Odd Degree) and Not Hamiltonian

$K_{1,2}$  --> Not Euler Circuit (Odd Degree) and Not Hamiltonian

$K_{2,2}$  --> Is Euler Circuit and is Hamiltonian

$K_{1,3}$  --> Not Euler Circuit (Odd Degree) and Not Hamiltonian

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct to me. Also, $K_{1,1}$ and $K_{1,2}$ have Euler/Hamiltonian paths; $K_{1,3}$ has nothin'.

Comment: Okay so the same rules do apply even if it is a Complete Bipartite Graph. Also $K_{4,4}$  would not be Hamiltonian correct?

Comment: $K_{n,n}$ is Hamiltonian for any $n>1$.